# how calculate size of objects in memory from ObjectGraphMeasure.measure method result from Caliper libraryin java?

Tags: java, memory

i want to calculate size of objects in netbeans, i try to use

```
long freeMem = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
long totalMem = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
```

but i notice that the result of this method change every time i run project,
then try to use `Caliper` library and use `ObjectGraphMeasure.measure` method that result :

```
Objects=270813, NonNullRefs=353968, NullRefs=1016731, Primitives=[int x 388091, double x 4375548, long x 2609976, boolean x 6398, float x 76765, char x 66658]
```

i want the size of object in bytes.

Comment: Check the following tool: https://github.com/dweiss/java-sizeof

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object/40764295#40764295